# Getting empty data from Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I have a firebase tree like this :

[image]

I want to retrieve this data into a JSON object

I tried the following code but its showing empty on my browser:

```
    const http = require('http');
const firebase = require('firebase');

 var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzjhjdfkjkfkjkjkfPSFNo3Eb-e2E",
    authDomain: "demoapp.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://demoapp-54551.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "demoapp-79516",
  };


var server = http.createServer((req,res)=>{

    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
}
    var db = firebase.database();
    var d = {}
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type','text/plain');


    var readRef = db.ref('categories');

    readRef.once('value', snapshot => {     
        var key = snapshot.key;
        d[key] = [];
        d[key].push(snapshot.val());        
    });


    res.end(JSON.stringify(d));    

});


server.listen(8080);
```

My result is empty object like below:

[image]

Please help me how to get Firebase data into a JSON string

Comment: how is your json formatted? share an example of that please. firebase has known issues with certain json objects

Comment: I should get data like this in my response { "category_name":"Lenses", "date_added":15252552}

Comment: that looks right...but i'm looking at your json and its throwing 404 https://demoapp-54551.firebaseio.com/.json so there is something wrong with the setup

Comment: Actually i edited this config variable in order to hide my application url. Its good while running i use actual configuration. My doubt is retrieving data from Firebase json tree.

Comment: @albert Can you elaborate on those known problems? If there's a problem with our database, I'd love to hear it so we can fix it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen null value issues. from what i was told, its an issue that will not be fixed. wrote up a gist for ya: https://gist.github.com/jalbertbowden/c41fd2945d3a510123d4ff9b0844f91b

Comment: Ah, array handling. That seems fairly far from this data model, but is indeed a weird case. Firebase doesn't store arrays natively. If you pass an array, it stores the data as regular key-value objects. This leads to problems if you later remove individual items, since the SDK may not detect that it used to be an array. See Kato's explanation here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html. In general: either treat arrays as atomic structure (always update the entire array), or preferably don't use arrays at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're trying to use the Firebase web/IoT SDK in a Cloud Function: `const firebase = require('firebase');`. That won't work.

Instead you should use the Firebase Admin SDK, as shown in all the samples: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#import_the_required_modules_and_initialize

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase); 
var db = admin.database();
```